# Fazer redirect para pasta específica assim que usuário acessar domínio

Tags: php

Sempre que o usuário acessar o site www.teste.com.br, quero que ele seja redirecionado para a pasta **/novo**. 
Exemplo: www.teste.com.br/novo
Tem como fazer isso em .php ou através do .htaccess?

Comment: Existem links que utilizam a URL antiga, por exemplo `www.teste.com.br/contato`? Se sim, o que deverá ser feito quando acessado?

Comment: Existe sim. Mais duas. /produtos e /contato. Ele deveria abrir /novo/produtos.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basta usares a  função nativa do php [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)
exemplo:

```
header('Location: www.site.com/novocaminho');
```

ou se preferires usa .htaccess, metes no diretorio raiz
exemplo:

```
Redirect 301 / http://site.com/novocaminho 
#tambem podes meter arquivos php
```

Comment: Fiz isso, mas ele está levando para teste.com.br/sitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesitesite - está criando vários "site".

Comment: Esse `sites` seria o `novo` que citou na pergunta? Isso se dá ao fato que a nova URL também casa com a expressão definida e é novamente redirecionada.

Comment: o site seria www.teste.com.br

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss exato, esse /site é o caminho onde quero redirecionar